# Custom Post Type same name as Category

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, categories

I have a general question. I'm using the plugin Custom Post Type UI. I named one of my post types marketing. However, I named one of my categories marketing too prior to installing the plugin. My question is, "Would this cause a problem"?

Comment: Define problem. term in taxonomy `marketing` will look like this `domain.com/marketing/my-term`, posts in post type `marketing` will look like this `domain.com/marketing/my-post`, there can be conflict if both term and post have the same slug. I don't know the precedence but I think in this situation term will always be interpreted first.

Comment: There’d be a conflict regardless of whether or not a term or post with the same slug existed. WordPress would 404 if there was no term with the slug in the URL. It wouldn’t then check for a post.